# Snowflake Stored Procedure Throws JavaScript Error

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When I run the script below by itself it works just fine:

```
set uuid = (select UUID_STRING());
select $uuid;
```

But when I run it inside a stored procedure it errors:
JavaScript compilation error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in sp_personinsert at '
> set uuid = (select UUID_STRING());' position 8

Comment: Could you provide your full javascript?  Also, out of curiosity, is there a reason you're setting SQL variables instead of using javascript variables?

Comment: are you using execute as caller or owner? This can affect how variables work.